# Specify two parameters in object to have same type

Tags: typescript

I currently have this simplified interface:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends MyType> {
  a: T,
  b: T[],
}

interface MyType {
  x: string,
  y: number,
}
```

I have several types/interfaces that implement the `MyType` interface, which are to be contained within `MyInterface`. What I specifically want with this interface, is that `a` and `b` contains the same type which implements `MyType`, but I do not particularly want that type to be variable/generic as it is now. Ideally, I would like to write:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a: T,
  b: T[],
}
```

Were T now is not an input, but in this example of course the type T is not specified and gives an error.

How can I make `a` and `b` contain the same type that implements `MyType` without having it as an generic input?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without generics. You have two constraints, that `a` and `b` have a linked relationship (namely that `b` is an array of `typeof a`), and that `a` can be multiple types. Your `MyInterface` is where you are defining the first requirement but in order to widen `a` to accept multiple potential types, you would use generics. An approach that only satisfied the second requirement would be to hardcode a number of `MyType` interfaces in which `b` was `(typeof a)[]`, but TypeScript would not know to complain if you deviated from this rule

Comment: What's the use case?  If I give you a `MyInterface`, would you want to know which `T` it is based on?  (If so then you want regular generics but maybe just want *inference* for `T`) Or will you only do operations where that information is unnecessary? (If so then you're looking for what's known as an *existential* generic type, but TS doesn't natively support those.  There are ways to encode them though).  And what operations would those be?

Comment: (continued) Also, because TS isn't really fully type safe, it's possible to widen any `MyInterface<T>` to `MyInterface<MyType>`, allowing unsafe operations as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvxGBN).  So depending on your use cases it might be that you should just replace `T` with `MyType` and give up on enforcing anything more specific.  So again, if you could augment your [mre] to show some use cases, it would help.